# Javascript - Push to a new array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I am new to javascript so I'm sorry in advance if my explanation is not the best.

I am getting my data back from an array called `myData`. I have a condition statement which checks the page url and depending on the url I am pushing a specific index of an array to a new array called `stateArray`

At the moment I am using the push method like this:

```
stateArray.push(myData[1][5], myData[2][5], myData[3][5], myData[4][5], myData[5][5], myData[6][5], myData[7][5], myData[8][5], myData[9][5], myData[10][5], myData[11][5], myData[12][5], myData[13][5], myData[14][5], myData[15][5], myData[16][5], myData[17][5], myData][5])
```

the return of `stateArray` is giving back the data I am expecting but I am going to have ten different conditions and would like to know if there is a way of doing the push 17 times for every condition better?

Every element is the same for the condition. For example

```
if (url.includes('/states/') {
stateArray.push(myData[1][5], myData[2][5], myData[3][5], myData[4][5], myData[5][5], myData[6][5], myData[7][5], myData[8][5], myData[9][5], myData[10][5], myData[11][5], myData[12][5], myData[13][5], myData[14][5], myData[15][5], myData[16][5], myData[17][5], myData][5])
} else if (url.includes('/homes/) {
stateArray.push(myData[1][6], myData[2][6], myData[3][6], myData[4][6], myData[5][6], myData[6][6], myData[7][6], myData[8][6], myData[9][6], myData[10][6], myData[11][6], myData[12][6], myData[13][6], myData[14][6], myData[15][6], myData[16][6], myData[17][6], myData][6])
} else if (url.incldues('/retail/) {
stateArray.push(myData[1][7], myData[2][7], myData[3][7], myData[4][7], myData[5][7], myData[6][7], myData[7][7], myData[8][7], myData[9][7], myData[10][7], myData[11][7], myData[12][7], myData[13][7], myData[14][7], myData[15][7], myData[16][7], myData[17][5], myData][7])

}
```

Like I mentioned earlier I currently have 10 conditions and it is very difficult to maintain and update. Is there a way of generating the same results dynamically? I believe this can be done through a loop but I am not familiar with the syntax in regards to pushing at a specific index and ending at a specific index.

My expected outcome is a short handed way of going through each condition and pushing into the new Array.

Comment: What's the `myData][5]` at the end meant to be? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach`:

```
if (url.includes('/states/')) {
  myData.forEach(e => stateArray.push(e[5]));
} else if (url.includes('/homes/')) {
  myData.forEach(e => stateArray.push(e[6]));
} else if (url.includes('/retail/')) {
  myData.forEach(e => stateArray.push(e[7]));
}
```

(Also note you need a second `)` at the end of your `if` to close off both the `if` and the `includes`)